# Write a function that returns avg arrival delay by carrier by airport in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have an airline delays data set with columns for carrier, origin airport, destination airport, dep delay, arr delay. How do I write a function that calculates and returns the average arrival delay for a carrier flying into the specified destination airport? This is what I have and it's not working.

```
avgDelay <- function(Carrier,Dest)
{
    x <- 0
    for (i in 1:dim(delays)[1])
    {
        for(j in 1:dim(delays)[1])
        {
            if(delays[i,3] == Carrier && delays[j,5] == Dest)
            {
                total <- x+(sum(delays[i,7] > 0, na.rm = TRUE))
                avg <- mean(total)
            }
        }
    }
    return(avg)
}
```

I want to run the function to return the average number of delays by carrier by destination airport

```
avgDelay("AA","LAX")
```

The data set looks something like this

```
  YEAR MONTH CARRIER ORIGIN DEST DEP_DELAY ARR_DELAY
1 2014     1      AA    JFK  LAX        14        13
2 2014     1      AA    JFK  LAX        -3         1
3 2014     1      AA    JFK  LAX        NA        NA
4 2014     1      AA    JFK  LAX        65        59
5 2014     1      AA    JFK  LAX       110       110
6 2014     1      AA    JFK  LAX        17        -8
```

Comment: It would help if you included a small example data set and the desired answer.  Your code should run and return an answer against which the desired answer can be compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for

```
   avgDelay <- function(carrier, dest)
{
     TempTotal = 0
     TempCount = 0 
     for(i in 1:dim(delays)[1]) 
     {
     if(delays$CARRIER[i] == carrier  & delays$ARR_DELAY[i] >0 & is.na(delays$ARR_DELAY[i]) == FALSE & delays$DEST[i] == dest) 
         {  
             TempTotal <-TempTotal + delays$ARR_DELAY[i] 
             TempCount <-TempCount + 1 # keeps count of the number of delays 
     }
 }
 return(TempTotal/TempCount) 
}

avgDelay("AA", "LAX")
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer would take more than 30 secs to execute.
The below code would be quicker as compared to the above one

```
AvgDelay<-function(x,y){
  output<-AirlineFile[(grepl(x,AirlineFile$CARRIER)&(grepl(y,AirlineFile$DEST))),]  
  returnValue(mean(output$ARR_DELAY[output$ARR_DELAY>0]))
}
```